# Parsing HTML String

Tags: c#, .net, html, parsing

Is there a way to parse HTML string in .Net code behind like DOM parsing...

i.e. GetElementByTagName("abc").GetElementByTagName("tag")

I've this code chunk...

```
private void LoadProfilePage()
{        
    string sURL;
    sURL = "http://www.abcd1234.com/abcd1234";

    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

    //WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy",80);
    //myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

    //wrGETURL.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();

    Stream objStream;
    objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

    if (objStream != null)
    {
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

        string sLine = objReader.ReadToEnd();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine) == false)
        {
            ....                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is valid XHTML perhaps you can load it in `System.Xml.XDocument`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the excellent [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/).

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Comment: dangit oded - I just posted this same thing only I'm slow and your a speed deamon! :) +1 from me.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at using the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Example of its use:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
```

Comment: xpath string should be "//a[@href]" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and a little XPath (it can even download the document for you):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.abcd1234.com/abcd1234");
HtmlNodeCollection tags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//abc//tag");
```

Comment: That link is outdated. They moved to http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to do  this exact thing and I think it's great.  It has been really helpful to me.

Comment: That link is outdated. They moved to http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)