# Click Image which then directs to a url in IE

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 App

In my MainPage.xaml I have the following:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" Margin="10,299,-40,0" Source="/Assets/Images/MTCOB.jpg"/>
```

What I want is for the user to tap this and then a website open in IE8.

In my MainPage.xmal.cs I have the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GamesWithGold.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace GamesWithGold
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

.............

I am new to this so would really like some help getting my first app out in BETA.

Comment: check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx you can create a instance of WebBrowsertask and assign a URI property to it

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191793/wp7-how-do-i-hide-or-remove-header-div-for-web-page

Comment: Just throw it in a [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowserTask BrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
            BrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com",UriKind.Absolute);
            BrowserTask.Show();
        }
```