# read a string from one point to another c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with string reading, I will explain the problem:

I have this code to read a web page and put it in a string:

```cs
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);

using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to take only some parts of this string, how can I do, if I use substring it doesn't take the selected pieces.

Example of a substring code:

```cs
Name = html.Substring((html.IndexOf("og:title")+19), (html.Substring(html.IndexOf("og:title") +19).FirstOrDefault(x=> x== '>')));
```

I would like it to start after the "og: title" and get to the '>', but it doesn't work.

The result is example:

```
"Valchiria “Intera” Pendragon\">\n<meta property=\"og:image\" conte"
```

Comment: You are fighting a losing battle, if you are trying to scrape html, use a dedicated html parser

Comment: Have you thought of using this code to download your page? `using (var wc = new WebClient()) html = wc.DownloadString(url);`

Comment: See `HtmlAgilityPack`, it fits your needs

Comment: How about an example/sample of the downloaded string?

Comment: the example is: <a href=\"/sets/1-cota/cards/10-loot-the-bodies\">Loot the Bodies</a> - <span class=\"type\">Action</span>\n\n @phuzi

Comment: @Mrpit Great, add that to the question - however, that will never be matched by your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier if you use a library to do it, for example you can take a look at [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-parse-html-in-NET-2660026c)

Your code, if I understood what you desire, should be like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string startingToken = "og:title\"";
    const string endingToken = "\">";

    var html = "<html><meta property=\"og:title\" Valchiria “Intera” Pendragon\">\n<meta property=\"og:image\" content></html>";

    var indexWhereOgTitleBegins = html.IndexOf(startingToken);
    var htmlTrimmedHead = html.Substring(indexWhereOgTitleBegins + startingToken.Length);

    var indexOfTheEndingToken = htmlTrimmedHead.IndexOf(endingToken);

    var parsedText = htmlTrimmedHead.Substring(0, indexOfTheEndingToken).TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');

    Console.WriteLine(parsedText);
}
```

Note that you can also use regular expressions to achieve the same in less line of code, but managing regex are not always easy.

Take a look at this answer:
[Parsing HTML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105379/parsing-html-string)

Your question title is probably not correct, because it looks more specific to HTML parsing.

Comment: I guess your `.TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ')` is equivalent to `.Trim(' ')`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, correct, but the purpose of this code is just to give an idea of what you would need to handle to get what I think was required, code such the one above would not be production code.